# Spring-boot multi module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

I have the following pom structure,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <revision>0.1.0</revision>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.7.5</spring-boot.version>
    <powermock.version>1.6.4</powermock.version>
    <common-lib.version>${revision}</common-lib.version>
    <maven-jacoco.version>0.8.6</maven-jacoco.version>
    <maven-surefire.version>3.0.0</maven-surefire.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- To build everything properly use "mvn clean install -Pbuild" -->
    <modules>        
        <module>common-lib</module>
        <module>my-service</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${common-lib.version}</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

common-lib's pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>

<!-- 
 Do not configure dependencies here (version, scope, exclusions, etc). Define them in a
 central place, the dependency management in the root pom.
-->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>    
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and service pox.xml as below,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

     <parent>
        <groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- 
     Do not configure dependencies here (version, scope, exclusions, etc). Define them in a
     central place, the dependency management in the root pom.
    -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- All spring-boot dependencies requires omitted-->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.xyz.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <!-- <executable>true</executable> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am running mvn package test and in local environment everything works fine and my-service.jar contains "common-lib" jar under BOOt_INF/lib but whenever I try to build it in Jenkins/CI I am getting a my-service.jar without common-lib packaged, though compilation succeeds in CI as well but fails when I run the application with "java.io.FileNotFoundException" exception. Can someone explain is anything wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above I accidentally ran `mvn package test` not `mvn test package` or `mvn package` which resulted into this error. Although I am not sure why running test phase later messed up the spring-boot jar packaging. I was able to reproduce the same in local environment.